# How do I tell Serde to deserialize an object in the order of a struct definition?

Tags: rust, serde

I'm trying to store the value of a field in a global context, but this doesn't work when the JSON object is in the wrong order.

How can I make it so the output is always, `a` then `b`?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=32488361b7b35da7628ae6de5a22c944)

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer};
use std::error::Error;

fn a_deserialize<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<u32, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let num = Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?;

    println!("a");

    Ok(num)
}

fn b_deserialize<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<u32, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let num = Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?;

    println!("b");

    Ok(num)
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Test {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "a_deserialize")]
    a: u32,
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "b_deserialize")]
    b: u32,
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    // notice the order is b then a
    let str = "{ \"b\": 1, \"a\": 2 }";

    let test: Test = serde_json::from_str(&str)?;
    // it prints out b then a, but I want a then b -- the same as in the struct definition

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear why you would do that — in theory, the deserialization process in itself should be relatively pure (in the sense that it doesn't have side effects) — so I'm not sure serde offers such a functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Serde was designed to incorporate a *stateful deserializer* which processes the various items in sequence, as the source data is consumed. As such, it is unrealistic to tell this deserializer to deserialize content in a different order. Given the JSON object

```json
{"b": 1, "a": 2}
```

`b` appears first, so that will be processed first. Anything else would have required the deserializer to keep track of potentially *all* data read in the past, keeping it "on hold" to visit it again at a later stage, making it more inefficient.

It is more realistic and feasible to adjust your program accordingly: visit the fields of a struct after it has been fully deserialized.

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Test {
    a: u32,
    b: u32,
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let str = "{ \"b\": 1, \"a\": 2 }";

    let test: Test = serde_json::from_str(&str)?;
    
    println!("a: {}", test.a);
    println!("b: {}", test.b);

    Ok(())
}
```

See also:

- [Access struct field by variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59600739)
- [How do I create mutable iterator over struct fields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61978903)

Comment: I agree that changing the order would be unrealistic in this situation, but as a nit: The deserializer must keep some information on hold for internally tagged enums, if the tag isn't the first entry. (Though I have no idea how that's internally implemented. Most likely, it just seeks forward, only keeping a pointer to the struct start.)

Comment: @Caesar Updated the answer a bit. Yes, there is always some state, but changing the order would bring that state to a whole other magnitude. :)