# Is there a way to use variables as key in an object to find its value in rust?

Tags: rust

I am new to rust with a javaScript background and i am stuck with getting a value of a json key dynamically.

In JS if i have an `object = { "xyz" : "one" , "jkl" : "two" };` and if i have a variable `name = "xyz";` , then i can find the corresponding value of 'xyz' key in the object using `object[name]` which will give me `"one"` as a result.

Now i have the exact same flow in rust, where i have

```
let obj = config.clone();     // because config is struct (only cloning could remove the error)
let name = "xyz";             // A variable which is a key in the object
let result = obj[name];`      // result which is giving me "cannot index into a value of type `Configuration`" error
```

I am aware that creating a dict or hashmap will exponentially reduce the time, but the object i have can contain upto 1000 keys and values or more.

If i can create a hashmap with the object I already have, that would be a relief ( only if i knew ).

I have tried multiple ways by just googling a bunch of stuff

1. `let result = obj[name];`
2. `let result = obj.&name];`
3. `let result = obj[$name];`
4. `let result = obj[&name];`
5. `let result = obj.$name;`

none of them seems to solve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type is `config` / how is `Confiration` defined? Please show a **complete** [mre].

Comment: Config is -> Configuration { test1: "one", test2: "two", test3: three, test4: "four" }  

as i could see in the println!();

Comment: Please read the link [mre], and when you've produced it [edit] your question to contain one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Accessing fields of structs dynamically is not possible out of the box. See this [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59600739/access-struct-field-by-variable) question.

Comment: When suggesting a duplicate it is customary not to add an answer.